# Submit pull request from child branch after parent branch is merged to upstream

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repo that has a remote upstream in Github. I created a branchA in my local repo for a new feature I was working on and then submitted a Pull Request for that branch. While waiting for this PR to be merged in upstream, I wanted to work on some more features that's based on branchA. So I created a new branchA1 from branchA and made some changes in that branch.

Now my PR for branchA is squash and merged to remote upstream in Github and I would like to submit a PR for my branchA1. What I did is that I first fetched the changes from remote upstream to my local master branch. Then I tried to do `git rebase master` in branchA1 but this command seems to be deleting all the changes I made in branchA1.

What is the best thing to do now if I would like to submit a PR from branchA1?

If I did something wrong in my workflow, what is the correct way to work on new features while waiting for a PR from parent branch to be merged?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TL;DR: you probably want `git rebase --onto` (which needs some extra parameters).

When you—or someone else; I'll use "they" here and assume someone—did a "squash and merge" on your original pull request, they *replaced* your commit(s) with a single new commit that they think is better than your original commit.

You, however, still have your original commit(s).  It's now your job to use `git rebase` to copy *only* the good commits on your `A1`, not any of the replaced-with-better commits that were on both `A1` and `A` and are now only on `A1`.

To put it in pictorial form, *you* had, e.g.:

```
...--o--o--A   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             B--C--D   <-- branch-A
                    \
                     E--F--G   <-- branch-A1
```

where each uppercase letter stands in for a commit, i.e., `A` is the hash ID of the commit that *was* at the tip of your (and their) `master` when you started, `B` is the first commit you made on your `branch-A`, and so on.

They then said: *OK, we like your `B-C-D` commits. But we're going to "improve" them by making a new commit `H` that's the result of **combining** `B` + `C` + `D` all into one big commit, which we'll put at the end of our `master` (your `origin/master`)*.  They may or may not have put some more commits in to their `master` in the meantime as well—let's draw in one round `o` to represent any such uninteresting commits.  As soon as you run `git fetch origin`, you get *their* **new** commits (you already have their old ones) into *your* repository, updating your `origin/master`:

```
             o--H   <-- origin/master
            /
...--o--o--A   <-- master
            \
             B--C--D   <-- branch-A
                    \
                     E--F--G   <-- branch-A1
```

If you `git checkout master` and `git merge origin/master`, you'll move your own `master` forward to match your `origin/master`:

```
...--o--o--A--o--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             B--C--D   <-- branch-A
                    \
                     E--F--G   <-- branch-A1
```

Your `branch-A` still exists, unless you specifically deleted it.  But even if you deleted it, you still have your `B-C-D` commits:

```
...--o--o--A--o--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- branch-A1
```

If you now `git checkout branch-A1` and `git rebase master`—whether or not you still have your name `branch-A` pointing to your commit `D` that they threw away in favor of their `H`—your Git will now try to copy *all six* commits, `B-C-D-E-F-G`, atop `H`, in an attempt to produce this:

```
                   B'-C'-D'-E'-F'-G'   <-- branch-A1 (rebased)
                  /
...--o--o--A--o--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             B--C--D--E--F--G   [abandoned]
```

But copying `B` atop `H` is not going to go well: it will conflict with itself, plus it needs the effect of `C` and `D` *removed*.  So this will look like you're trying to remove your own code, only to put it back again when you copy `C` to `C'` and later `D` to `D'`.  In any case *all* of that is useless.

What you'd like to tell Git, at this point, is not: *Copy all of my commits on `branch-A1` that aren't on `master`, to go after `H` at the tip of `master`*, but rather: *Copy only **some** of my commits on `branch-A1` that aren't on `master`, to go after `H` at the tip of `master`*.  The set of commits that you want to copy, in this particular example, is `E-F-G`.  You want to *end up* with:

```
                   E'-F'-G'   <-- branch-A1 (rebased)
                  /
...--o--o--A--o--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             B--C--D--E--F--G   [abandoned]
```

The *way* to tell Git that is to use `git rebase --onto`, which takes *two* arguments instead of just one.  You want to rebase *onto `master`, and you want to exclude commit `D` and anything earlier (`C`, `B`, `A`, and all the boring commits to the left of `A`).  So, if you *do* still have the name `branch-A` identifying commit `D`, you can use:

```
git checkout branch-A1             # make sure you're on the right branch
git rebase --onto master branch-A  # tell Git: copy only commits after branch-A
```

If you *don't* have the name `branch-A`, you can use a raw commit hash ID as the limiter instead of the name `branch-A`, or you can run `git rebase -i master` and *delete* the unwanted `pick` commands; or you can run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` and count commits, or whatever you need, to find the commit.

Note that after rebasing, you have a *new* `branch-A1` (completely unrelated by *history* to your earlier `branch-A1`, even though the three commits are copied so as to have the same effect).  You will therefore need to force-push this to whatever web service you are using to handle pull requests (apparently GitHub).  You can use `--force-with-lease` if you're worried that someone else might be adding commits to your `branch-A1` on the GitHub server.